# Databricks SQL - Max count simultaneous events in intervals

Tags: sql, databricks, simultaneous

I'm using databricks and I have a 150 million row dataset "df1" with the following columns:

- event_id
- event_group_id
- starttime (timestamp)
- endtime (timestamp)

[You can see an example of "df1" here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzDa0.png)

I want to create another dataset "df2" counting all simultaneous events and, for every 5 min time window, get the maximum value. Also, I need it for every group_event_id. The "df2" dataset should be like this:

- time_window
- event_group_id
- max_event_count

[You can see an example of "df2" here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qRtt.png)

I would like to start the time_window column with the time window right before minimum starttime and finish it with the time window right after maximum endtime.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to query and join a lot!  You could get a distinct list of group, critical times ctime by a union of start and end times (derived table), then join that to your table aggregate for each group and ctime how many group = and start >= ctime and end < ctime (assuming end time is not included).  The window is from one ctime to the next within the group.  That might be better done in post-processing.